# How to dynamically create DIV tags IDs

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have an array of values that I am trying to use as the ID when creating my div tags dynamically.

I am using MVC knockout and have an observableArray that contains the values.

In my html, I am looping through the list of value. How can I create each DIV tag but specify the value from the list as it's ID?

```
<!-- ko foreach: myList -->
<div data-bind="html: $data">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the value from the list," but something like this:

```
<div data-bind="html: $data, attr: {id: value}">
</div>
```